# ios scrollView can not scroll

Tags: ios

When I set the following the UIWebView inside the scrollView can not scroll and the web page is cut off.

```
scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-150,0.0,0,0.0),
```

However, when I set this it works well.

```
_scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(150,0.0,0,0.0),
```

What's more, if I set this in the UIWebView delegate function "viewDiappear", it works well too.

```
_scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-150,0.0,0,0.0)
```

This only happens in ios8 and ios9.

Comment: this happen only on a html page

Comment: Please define your exact question.

Comment: I tried to  set _scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-150,0.0,0,0.0) in viewWillAppear and viewDidLoad, but it fail

Comment: I have a scrollView and inside the scrollView, there is a UIWebView, when i set scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-150,0.0,0,0.0) in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear, I found the html page in the UIWebView can not scroll to the bottom, it seems that it is cut off. But if I set set scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-150,0.0,0,0.0) in the viewDidAppear delegate function, it work well

Comment: why do u need a webview inside a scrollview?

Comment: sorry, that's a scrollview inside a webview

Answer (score 0):

The Apple docs explicitly say you should NOT embed a `UIWebView` in a `UIScrollView`.

[image]

The `UIWebView` conforms to `UIScrollViewDelegate`. So you can directly adjust the `contentInsets` of the `UIWebView` itself.

Comment: sorry, i made a mistake, that's a scrollview inside a webview